# Unable to Integrate the Digital Advertising Tracking Scripts in the DWT

Tags: 2009

There are few digital advertising tracking scripts from some vendors such as Bizo and Geocommerce etc. I am integrating these scripts in the Dreamweaver TBB of a page template. In page preview I am able to see the desired output. When I publish the page deployment gets failed and through below error –

> Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed, Could not transform tcdl file /opt/apps/lisdl/XYZ/temp/Zip/tcm_0-299595-66560.Content/Pages/na/transformed/index.jsp, Could not transform tcdl input string Unable to transform input string, Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="" Source (45156) : Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="", Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="" Source (45156) : Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="", Could not transform tcdl input string Unable to transform input string, Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="" Source (45156) : Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="", Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="" Source (45156) : Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="", Could not transform tcdl file /opt/apps/lisdl/XYZ/temp/Zip/tcm_0-299595-66560.Content/Pages/na/transformed/index.jsp, Could not transform tcdl input string Unable to transform input string, Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="" Source (45156) : Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="", Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="" Source (45156) : Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="", Could not transform tcdl input string Unable to transform input string, Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="" Source (45156) : Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="", Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId="" Source (45156) : Expected whitespace after tag attribute linkAttributes=" class="frame"" textOnFail="true" addAnchor="false" variantId=""

It seems that something(code/characters) in the scripts are not allowed by the deployer.

Why does this error come at deployment time only and not during the rendering phase?

Comment: It would be helpful if you share your DWT code.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the `linkAttributes` bit is the problem.  You have being rendered out:

```
linkAttributes=" class="frame""
```

which looks like it should be more `linkAttributes="class='frame'"`

Check quote/speech mark usage in the link attributes being rendered out in your TBB and correct as needed using alternative quotes or `&#34;`

Comment: Thanks Dave for your answer.Let me check it. I have a question in my head. why it is happening at the time of deployment not at the time of rendering ? could you please clear my this doubt also ?

Comment: the TCDL is transformed by the Deployer, so that might be the reason why it is not causing an issue at rendering time